# Connecting Actionscript 3.0 and PHP?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have created this drag and drop application using Actionscript, and would like to send variables from here to a MySQL database. But before that, I intend to store the variables as session variables.

I'm not really sure on how to go about doing this and I haven't found anything much online that is relevant. Could someone show me how the PHP and Actionscript side code looks like?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please post the source-code of that application your question is about.

Answer (score 1):

No-one here is going to write all that code for you.

The simple stages would be like this;
Have a PHP file for each service (maybe called "writeVariable" and another called "readVariable"). Decide on some way to pass information to and from them - maybe using JSON or XML, or just plaintext. The services would then write and read the data from the database as needed.

Then access those pages from flash through URLLoader and the protocol you set up.